# How to draw a line under street name using MapBox

Tags: ios, mapbox

I would like to draw a route using Mapbox. I've tried adding polyline:

```
let polyline = MGLPolyline(coordinates: &coords, count: UInt(coords.count))
mapView?.add(polyline)
```

But it keeps drawing on top of street names. How can I move below street names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add an `MGLPolyline` directly to an `MGLMapView`, you’re adding it as an annotation; currently the Mapbox iOS SDK only supports adding annotations on top of everything.

However, the SDK has a separate API called [*runtime styling*](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.5.3/runtime-styling.html), which allows you to place data under or above any layer of the map. From [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/runtime-add-line/), you can use code like the following to add a *shape source* to the map’s style and a *line layer* that renders the shape source. (`MGLLineStyleLayer` is reminiscent of MapKit’s `MKOverlayPathRenderer`.)

```
let routeFeature = MGLPolylineFeature(coordinates: &coords, count: UInt(coords.count))
let routeSource = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "route", shape: routeFeature, options: nil)
mapView.style?.addSource(routeSource)
let routeLayer = MGLLineStyleLayer(identifier: "route", source: routeSource)
// Set properties like lineColor, lineWidth, lineCap, and lineJoin
mapView.style?.insertLayer(routeLayer, above: roadLayer) // or below: labelLayer
```

The code above works if you know the identifier of the road or label layer. You can obtain the identifier by opening the style in [Mapbox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/studio/). For something more robust, you could iterate over all the layers in the map style, inserting the route layer above the first non-symbol layer you find. (Labels and icons are rendered using symbol layers.)

```
for layer in style.layers.reversed() {
    if !(layer is MGLSymbolStyleLayer) {
        style.insertLayer(routeLayer, above: layer)
        break
    }
}
```

By the way, if you need more than just a route line, [Mapbox Navigation SDK for iOS](https://www.mapbox.com/navigation-sdk/) comes with a complete turn-by-turn navigation UI, including a map that’s optimized for displaying a route.

Comment: If I know the identifier, how should I create `roadLayer`? I've tried like this 
`let roadLayer = MGLStyleLayer(identifier: "roadLayerIdentifier")` and it fails when I try to add `routeLayer`, here: `mapView?.style?.insertLayer(routeLayer, above: roadLayer)`

Comment: @Xernox, `MGLStyleLayer(identifier:)` creates a new style layer. To get a reference to the existing style layer representing roads, call the `layer(withIdentifier:)` method on `MGLStyle`.

Comment: This is perfect for iOS. Thank you very much for the solution. I did same kind of work on Android. But it is not working as expected. Do you have any idea about that?

Answer (score 0):

People coming here for **Mapbox version 10** can use the below.

If the *street name layer* is below the line layer use this:
.withRouteLineBelowLayerId("road-label-street")


If the *annotation layer* is below the line layer use this:
.withRouteLineBelowLayerId("mapbox-android-pointAnnotation-layer-1")

**NOTE:** This is the **kotlin version** but you can use the layer ID as it's the same for your case such as *react-native*